# declaring PHP variables inside a loop with concatenation

Tags: php, variables, loops, concatenation

I need to make PHP variables all starting with $hex followed by numbers 1-8.

In a loop, can I concatenate the increment, `i`, with the variable, like this:

```
$hex . i
```

Or will that not work?

EDIT: never mind, I figured it out: `${ }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use eval php function:

```
eval('$hex'. $i . ';');
```